# Dictate: Speech to Text

Tags: feature-request

Our community types a lot - question, answers, comments, etc. How about introducing a feature to dictate instead of typing? That will save a lot of hours of typing and improve the productivity for SO users.

The hack is to dictate it somewhere else for e.g. I use Outlook desktop client to dictate and then copy-paste on SO. Do you think having a dictation feature in-place would be great?

If this goes well, it could open up a great area of work for SO using speech like "Open the close votes review queue", "How many questions with algorithms tag have bounty open right now?", etc.

Comment: Adding voice commands for site navigation sounds like a ton of developer work for an extremely marginal benefit.

Comment: Developer work is a lot for sure. But someday it needs to start. May be we can just start with the speech in comment section and see how it goes.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni This feature is not worth enough for the work tht it will take to implement.

Comment: I guess it'll be worth it. Using APIs would cut down the efforts. Need not train our own speech to text models for that. Yeah, but definitely it is futuristic. YMMV.

Comment: Why does it need to start? What problem does this solve?

Comment: I could not imagine that I could dictate ``.map((el, idx) => el.innerHTML + document.querySelector(`#par${idx}`).innerHTML)`` faster than I could type it. "dot map open parenthesis open parenthesis e ell comma space eye dee ex close parenthesis space equals symbol greater than symbol space e ell dot inner capital H capital T capital M capital L space plus symbol space document dot query capital S elector" I've already typed the code twice.

Comment: The cost/benefit ratio for this is quite low (i.e. the cost is high and the benefit is low). It's *not* a trivial problem. Multiple other companies have been working on it, some for decades. It's still not a *solved* problem. There's *lots* of things which SO's developers could be working on which would provide *substantially* more benefit to the site, community, and company. Those users who want speech to text functionality can already obtain one of several products which provide speech to text for them and which work with basically any application on their machine, including with browsers.

Comment: Why is this a feature that Stack Overflow has to implement? There are already text to speech tools built in operating systems and browsers (IIRC, usually as plugins). So, why should SO implement (at least) a third way to type as dictation?

Comment: You're asking for two things here: dictation and voice commands. They both use your voice, but they're both very different features.

Comment: Having a little bit more content on the SO is a little advantage. Having much more illiterate post authors on the site is an unthinkable disadvantage. What I would more prefer: having some spellchecking system what gives automatic downs for the people simply not wanting to use punctuations, capital letters and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using speech to text to write this:

> You can check out the documentation of the `.remove()` method [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ).

The markdown of that looks like this:

> `You can check out the documentation of the .remove() method [here](https://example.com).`

Not only that, but speech to text isn't exactly.... reliable. It can misunderstand a lot of what you say. To make it accurate and easy to use is even harder from the developers perspective.

If you *really* want speech to text, you can use [one of the thousands of available](https://www.google.com/search?q=speech+to+text&oq=speech+t&aqs=chrome.0.0i67i433j69i57j0i67l4j69i60l2.1998j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) speech to text websites.

---

> If this goes well, it could open up a great area of work for SO using speech like "Open the close votes review queue", "How many questions with algorithms tag have bounty open right now?", etc.

Firstly, I'd like to say that that's a great idea that would work very well.

But to implement that, first we would need to hear what is said properly (which is a lot of work already). Once that is done, we need to structurally break up the sentence to see what is being asked, and then using a machine learning algorithm, figure out what the person is actually asking, and then convert that into instructions for the machine.

Products like Alexa and Google Home are focused *entirely* upon that because it is such a challenging task. Google had to use their extremely complicated AI networks to do what you are asking here. How can a website, which is not focused on speech to text, do something like that?

It's just not worth the time that it will take.

Comment: In your answer itself, text to speech could have saved a lot of time. We can't expect to use speech commands for formatting as of today for sure. I think the APIs have great accuracy. The aim is not to achieve 100% but a start today will definitely help in future.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Sure, text to speech could have saved me some time. But it would be akward, wouldn't it? Talking to your computer? What if you are in a noisy place? What if you don't have a mic? And lastly, why not just type the post out anyways? As Makyen said, the cost is high compared to the benefit. If you want text to speech, use the feature in google docs and then copy over whatever you have.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I used the voice typing feature in google docs, and there are three notable points: What if I want to type "period" with voice typing? If I say "period" it will type `.`. In fact, ending sentences with punctuation is impossible with speech to text. Plus, for some accents, it is not accurate enough.

Comment: I yell and curse a lot at my computer. If that speech makes it into text I get suspended. Causing more yelling and cursing which doesn't help my case ...

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni "*In your answer itself, text to speech could have saved a lot of time*" For generating the content - perhaps. How much time would it take to then apply formatting correctly and edit everything that was wrong?